# Laravel project not working on server it's working fine in localhost

Tags: php, laravel

My code is below i tried changing so many things but nothing works and it's working fine on localhost.

**Here is my index.php file code**

```
 require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';


 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**Here is my .env file code**

```
        APP_ENV=local
        APP_DEBUG=true
        APP_KEY=base64:c3cmwqasuiz9nMLjHSaBHHnLtjtMzRDCCN1rhQfz6aQ=
        APP_URL=http://duskysol.move.pk

        DB_CONNECTION=mysql
        DB_HOST=sql304.move.pk
        DB_PORT=3306
        DB_DATABASE=mov_20065899_myportfolio
        DB_USERNAME=mov_20065899
        DB_PASSWORD=********
        CACHE_DRIVER=file
        SESSION_DRIVER=file
        QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

        REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
        REDIS_PASSWORD=null
        REDIS_PORT=6379

        MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
        MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
        MAIL_PORT=2525
        MAIL_USERNAME=null
        MAIL_PASSWORD=null
        MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on reading your question and your comments below I would check the following.

1. Make sure that /storage folder exists and that it has proper folder permission you can use 777 for testing, but make sure to change it when you are done. To do this type `sudo chmod 0777 -R /storage` when inside root.
2. Make sure you have your encryption type set to `AES-256-CBC` inside of `/config/app.php`
3. Make sure you have generated an application key by running this in the root folder `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 2):

- Move .htaccess file public to root.
- Check .htaccess code it should be like below one.

  Options -MultiViews -Indexes

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  ```

> If again it will not work, then open terminal and run update composer
>   command.

Comment: thankuu i change on my server .htaccess file and its work on root(domain) but how to run on subfolder or subdomain ?